# How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when testing .NET Core 2.0 class library with xUnit in VS2017

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit

I use this code to load settings depending on Environment in my **xUnit test project**:

```
public class TestSettings
{
    public string AzureConnectionString { get; }

    public TestSettings(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        string envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        output.WriteLine($"env: '{envVariable}'");

        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envVariable}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
        AzureConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("AzureStorage");
    }
}
```

But whatever I do I get `envVariable` empty. Where can I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for test project (VS2017)?

**To ASP.NET Core Tooling Team**

Please make test project settings work for environment. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to set environment variables, or how to set environment variables such that they only apply in your test environment?

Comment: Do you see Environment Variables section when you go to project properties and choose Debug tab?

Comment: I saw it. And set it. And it doesn't work. Remember, this is a test project.

Comment: Marc, I'm asking how to actually set up ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable when running tests. I tried Debug section in the properties and launchSettings.json. Nothing works ... for me.

Comment: On windows go to command prompt and enter set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development on macOS open terminal and enter export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

Comment: Yeah, that's new :) But thanks anyway. I really hope asp.net core tooling team reads this and I hope test project settings will have effect in the near future. Because I work on different projects and some of them run in dev mode, some in release. It's not very convenient to do this from command line when you have two places in VS2017 where you can set them.

Comment: @alvipeo this is a common issue. Here check this out
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/456#issuecomment-333787485

Comment: you can always create an additional profile. that's what i always do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should GetEnvironmentVariable Work in xUnit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927955/should-getenvironmentvariable-work-in-xunit-test)

Comment: 3 years later I don't actually care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, on Windows set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with this command:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
```

so the value stays (notice the 'set***x***').

Also, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951218/2896495.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT does not work for me in either pre- or post-build event

Answer (score 2):

In your setup you can add:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");